# How can I create a soft link(symbolic link) under /sys/kernel/config/nvmet/ports?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, symlink, sysfs, nvme

Since I am trying to configure the NVMet-RDMA target on the server, I want to create a symbolic link by the following command(according to https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/managing_storage_devices/overview-of-nvme-over-fabric-devicesmanaging-storage-devices#setting-up-nvme-rdma-target-using-nvmetcli_nvme-over-fabrics-using-rdma):

```
sudo ln -s /sys/kernel/config/nvmet/subsystems/testnqn   /sys/kernel/config/nvmet/ports/1/subsystems/testnqn
```

but this command returns errors like "argument invalid". What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

don't put the name of the file in the target link argument:

```
sudo ln -s /sys/kernel/config/nvmet/subsystems/testnqn   /sys/kernel/config/nvmet/ports/1/subsystems/
```

it will have the same name of the original.

Comment: I see, but I still get the error "failed to create symbolic link ‘/sys/kernel/config/nvmet/ports/1/subsystems/testnqn’: Invalid argument" : - (

Comment: try to use the -- command line switch  ln -s --

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had missed a setting `addr_adrfam` in the port configuration.  After correcting this issue I was able to create the symlink without any invalid argument errors.  Essentially, if there is a configuration issue with the port, you will be unable to create the symlink.

Since there are likely multiple sources that can cause this problem, the best idea is to check dmesg for the specific error.  For example, I was able to find the following error in dmesg: `nvmet_rdma: address family 0 not supported`.